# Specifying mesh in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a system of one-dimensional two-point boundary-value problems with NDSolve.  I would like use a fixed mesh (specified by me) in the calculation.  Is there a way to do this?  The mesh can be uniformly spaced.  Thanks!

Comment: Providing an example of what you want may improve this question.

Answer (score 4):

First the mesh where you want NDSolve to solve the ODE-BVP.

```
(*Specifyling grid*)
{start, end, dist} = {0, 1, 1/10};
SuppliedMesh = N@Range[start, end, dist]
```

> {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}

Now lets solve an example system below on the specified grid

```
(* Solving and saving the grid NDSolve uses *)
{sol, {grid}} = 
Reap[y /. Flatten@
 NDSolve[{y''[t] + y[t]/4 == 8, y[start] == 0, y[end] == 0}, 
  y, {t, start, end}, StartingStepSize ->dist, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[t],Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}]
];
(* Value of the interpolating function on its underlying mesh*)
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[sol]
```

> {0., -0.366755, -0.653511, -0.85935, -0.983554, -1.02561, -0.985208, -0.862242, -0.656812, -0.369227, 1.66533*10^-16}

Checking if the mesh matches really the supplied one.

```
SuppliedMesh === grid === Flatten@InterpolatingFunctionGrid[sol]
```

> True

**PS:**

Now in place of supplying the mesh to `NDSolve` better one should try to make `NDSolve` make/use it in run-time while solving the equation by tuning its stepping algorithm. You will find such trick in [NDSolvePlugIns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html).

BR

Comment: nice answer. You can also use `InterpolatingFunctionGrid[sol]` to extract the grid points.